# Why will my valid DDL not run with Liquibase?

Tags: sql, mariadb, liquibase

I have a statement that runs fine using a mysql editor like Heidi, but returns an un-useful syntax error when run by liquibase. This is my changeset:

```
--changeset name-20180416:2 endDelimeter:\$\$
ALTER TABLE myschema.MiscFileStore MODIFY COLUMN Description VARCHAR(4000)$$
```

Here is the output from maven/Liquibase:

> Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Liquibase fails against the same database that I am successfully running the statement against using Heidi.

DB version is:

> 10.0.17-MariaDB-log, InnoDB

Liquibase version:

> ```
> <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
> <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
> <version>3.3.2</version>
> ```

Comment: Try running the updateSQL command rather than the update command - that might show if your SQL is getting altered along the way. I have no data to support this, but I am speculating that the $$ delimiter is possibly confusing liquibase.

Comment: Thanks SteveDonie. I tried other statements in place of the alter, to make sure there was not some sort of systemic problem. The $$ delimiter was quickly ruled out as a non issue. For example, this ran fine:
--changeset stan-20180416:1 endDelimeter:\$\$
drop table if exists bid.adam14568965863468$$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though. I am reading about the updateSQL goal, to see how it can be used.

Comment: Why are you using `$$`?

Comment: Out of habit for all of our changesets. Sometimes stored procedures get ended early if semi colon is used externally and for statements internal to the sp.  Using a different delimiter is a good, common way to avoid that. It is not necessary in this case, but also not causing any problems. The statement fails regardless of the delimiter being used.